# Arrowheads made up of other arrowheads

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, arrows

I'd like to make an arrowhead that is a filled circle surrounded by an arc. I can make this by putting an `Arc Barb` and a `Circle` on each other, but the problem is their spacing breaks up depending on the arrowhead is at the start or at the end:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\newcommand*{\ioport}{[sep=1mm]{Arc Barb}[reversed,scale=1.6,sep=-1mm]{Circle}}

\tikzset
  { >={direction ee}
  }

\pgfsetarrowoptions{direction ee}{5pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[{\ioport<}-{<\ioport}] (0,0) -- (10,0);
  \draw[{\ioport>}-{>\ioport}] (10,-1) -- (0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As the result shows, the arrowhead is exactly as I'd like at the end of lines, but it falls apart at the start of lines:

[image]

I'd like to change `\ioport` so that it can be used at both ends of edges.

One horrible workaround I've found is to create two distinct commands for the two line-ends:

```
\newcommand*{\ioportstart}{[sep=1mm]{Circle}[sep=0mm]{Arc Barb}[reversed,sep=-1mm,scale=1.6]} 
\newcommand*{\ioportend}{[sep=1mm]{Arc Barb}[reversed,sep=-1mm,scale=1.6]{Circle}[sep=0mm]}
```

but I really want to avoid having to use a different name at the two line-ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nuclear option is to give up on composing arrows, and draw it myself:

```
\pgfarrowsdeclare{io}{io}
 {
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{-8\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{8\pgflinewidth}}
 {
   \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{8\pgflinewidth}{0}}{4\pgflinewidth}
   \pgfusepathqfill
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{8\pgflinewidth}{-8\pgflinewidth}}
   \pgfpatharc{270}{90}{8\pgflinewidth}
   \pgfusepathqstroke
 }

\newcommand*{\ioport}{[sep=1mm]{io}[sep=1mm]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure which ones of the arrows you want, but for example, looking at page 210 of the manual, I came up with this:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\tikzset{myr/.tip = {<[sep=1mm]{Arc Barb}[scale=1.6,sep=0mm]{Circle}},
    my-my/.tip = {myr[reversed]},
    >={direction ee},
    }
\pgfsetarrowoptions{direction ee}{5pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[my-] (0,-2) -- ++(10,0) node[midway, fill=white]{1};
  \draw[-my] (0,-3) -- ++(10,0) node[midway, fill=white]{2};
  \draw[my-my] (0,-4) -- ++(10,0) node[midway, fill=white]{3};
  \draw[my-] (10,-5) -- ++(-10,0) node[midway, fill=white]{4};
  \draw[-my] (10,-6) -- ++(-10,0) node[midway, fill=white]{5};
  \draw[my-my] (10,-7) -- ++(-10,0) node[midway, fill=white]{6};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Basically, you define the right-to-left tip (I think, don't trust me on left-right statements!) and then the `my-my` trick does the extension to the three basic forms.

Comment: +1. I am not sure, that the "`my-my` trick" does anything (other than you use `reversed`, that can also be used directly in the tip definition). I do not think that the manual describe this in a good way.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Yes, I agree (I +1ed yours too). I just tried ;-)

Comment: But I don't want to bake in the `<`/`>` arrowhead into the `my` arrowhead, I want to be able to write `my>->my` or `my<-<my` etc, i.e. combine them freely.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I  didn't understand it. No idea if it's possible; probably you need to define all possible combinations...

Answer (score 3):

This is just an extension of @Rmano excellent answer. By trail, it seems that it is not needed to first define one tip, and then extend it to both directions. -it works with just one tip:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\tikzset{my/.tip = {>[sep=1mm]{Arc Barb}[scale=1.6, reversed, sep=-1mm]{Circle}}, >={direction ee}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[my-] (0,-2) -- ++(10,0) node[midway, fill=white]{1};
  \draw[-my] (0,-3) -- ++(10,0) node[midway, fill=white]{2};
  \draw[my-my] (0,-4) -- ++(10,0) node[midway, fill=white]{3};
  \draw[my-] (10,-5) -- ++(-10,0) node[midway, fill=white]{4};
  \draw[-my] (10,-6) -- ++(-10,0) node[midway, fill=white]{5};
  \draw[my-my] (10,-7) -- ++(-10,0) node[midway, fill=white]{6};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Arrows]